# Can i customize IBM bluemix android watson app?

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

Can I use ibm bluemix android chatbot-watson-android code base and customize it as per my needs? like change the name of app, package name and code?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the projects on GitHub are open source, so yes you can modify them as you wish.  Read the License.txt file in those projects for details.  if you are looking for examples of Watson projects, the [Starter Kits](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/starter-kits.html) are another great resource.

A quick note.  Some of the GitHub projects that you may find get deployed to Bluemix.  If they do, then order to change the name of the app and the package, you'll have to make changes in both Bluemix and in your manifest.yml and package.json files.

Answer (score 1):

The project [chatbot-watson-android](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/chatbot-watson-android) is open source, so you can implement and change what you want, is built from one IBM Professional, and you can saw more about this projects in the [IBM Cloud Blog - Build a voice-enabled Chatbot in minutes using Watson Java and Android SDKs](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/01/build-voice-enabled-chatbot-minutes/).

And has other [Project](https://github.com/YnotZer0/android_conversation) from another IBM Developer called Android Conversation, you can saw step-by-step in this [Official link](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/making-an-android-mobile-app-that-uses-the-ibm-watson-conversation-service-as-a-chatbot/) in Developers Works website.

You can access the Official [Java SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk) (Supports Android) and the [Android SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk) for view other Watson APIs Services.

In the Android SDK has official's Example to call some services, you can take a look at this [link](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk/tree/master/example).

- See the Official API Reference for [Watson Conversation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/).
- See the Official API Reference for [Speech to Text](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/?java#).

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming the android Watson app you are talking about is this one - https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/chatbot-watson-android. Take a look at the license file. It is located here: https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/chatbot-watson-android/blob/master/License.txt. IBM has released this code base under Apache V2 license. You can use this code for your usage. But do read up on Apache V2 licensing terms.

Typically you can fork the repo under your GitHub account and work from there. You can additionally download the source code to your workstation and go ahead from there.